# Creating separate columns within barplot

Tags: r

I have two columns in my data airlines and sentiment (which are coded as zero and one). I have created a bar plot with the code below but I would like the zero and ones to be separated into separate boxes. I have used "dodge" but I haven't been able to get it working.

Thank you for your help in advance!

```
1 airline               sentiment 
2 Virgin                     0
3 America airways            1
4 Jet Blue                   0
5 Virgin                     1
6 Virgin                     1
7 America airways            0
8 Jet Blue                   1
9 Virgin Virgin               0
10 America airways             0
11 Jet Blue                    1
12 Virgin                      1
```

The code below results in this plot:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EBEL6.png)

```
ggplot(airline_sentiment, aes(x=airline, y = sentiment)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity", aes(fill = sentiment))+
  ggtitle("") +
   xlab("Airline") + ylab("Frequency") + theme(legend.position = "none")
```

When I use:

```
#using dodge
ggplot(airline_sentiment, aes(x=airline, y = sentiment, fill = sentiment)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge")

#using facet wrap
ggplot(airline_sentiment, aes(x=airline, y = sentiment, fill = sentiment)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity") + facet_wrap(~sentiment)
```

My code doesn't split into columns like you have suggested rather splits like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VToGH.png)

Thank you again!

Comment: `ggplot(airline_sentiment, aes(x=airline, y = sentiment)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity", aes(fill = sentiment), position=position_dodge())+
  ggtitle("") +
   xlab("Airline") + ylab("Frequency") + theme(legend.position = "none")` ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exactly you mean with "different boxes". Here two possibilities using just a few rows of your data

```
#using dodge
ggplot(airline_sentiment, aes(x=airline, y = sentiment, fill = sentiment)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge")

#using facet wrap
ggplot(airline_sentiment, aes(x=airline, y = sentiment, fill = sentiment)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity") + facet_wrap(~sentiment)
```

[image: dodge]

[image: facet wrap]